# c# change panel color from another form

Tags: c#, forms, panel

I'm stuck with the following thing.
I want to change the panel color from another Form(ColorForm).
Is it possible?

Code From the MainForm:

```
public void upperpanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

I don't know how to access that upperpanel_Paint in my ColorForm.
 I'm opening ColorForm From SettingsForm

> Mainform > SettingsForm > ColorForm

```
public partial class SettingsForm : Form
{

    public static event ColourSettingChangedDelegate ColourSettingsChangedEvent;
    public delegate void ColourSettingChangedDelegate(Color color);


    List<string> adreses;

    List<string> bookmarki;

    void SelectColour()
    {
        using (ColorForm colourForm = new ColorForm())
        {


            if (colourForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                //Update colour setting and fire event
                OnColourSettingsChanged(colourForm.SelectedColor);
            }
        }
    }



    public SettingsForm(List<string> adr, List<string> s)
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        adreses = adr;
        bookmarki = s;


    }




    private void Historyb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Form form in Application.OpenForms)
        {


            if (form.GetType() == typeof(HistoryForm))
            {
                form.Activate();
                return;
            }
        }

        HistoryForm hf1 = new HistoryForm(adreses);

        hf1.Show();
    }

    private void Bookmarksb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BookmarksForm booklist = new BookmarksForm();
        booklist.SetAllBookmarks(bookmarki);
        booklist.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void Colorb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SelectColour();

    }





    private void OnColourSettingsChanged(Color color)
    {
        if (ColourSettingsChangedEvent != null)
            ColourSettingsChangedEvent(color);
    }


}
```

Code from ColorForm:

```
 public partial class ColorForm : Form
{

    public ColorForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }



    private void Panelcolor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ColorDialog colorDlg = new ColorDialog();
        colorDlg.AllowFullOpen = true;
        colorDlg.AnyColor = true;

        if (colorDlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            upperpanel.BackColor = colorDlg.Color;


        }
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are you opening the ColorForm from the MainForm?

Comment: To open Form i have to go through MainForm > SettingsForm > ColorForm

Comment: where does the `upperpanel` instance in `ColorForm.Panelcolor_Click` come from? is the `upperpanel` modifier in `MainForm` public?

Comment: `upperpanel.BackColor = colorDlg.Color;`  does not work. I understand that my ColorForm does not recognize my "upperpanel"  who is public in `Mainform `

Comment: I think you need to create an Event in the SettingForm (something like SettingsUpdated) and let your main form subscribe to the event. When the ColorDialog closes and you update the setting in the SettingForm, you can raise the event and if the MainForm has subscribed the event you can update the panel with code directly inside the main form class.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it would be better to fire a global event when the settings change, or the particular form colour setting changes, and listen for that event on the form where you need to take action.

for example see this pseudo code:

ColourForm:

Form used just to pick a colour, and store the result in a property.

```
class ColourForm
{
   public Color SelectedColor {get;set;}

    private void Panelcolor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ColorDialog colorDlg = new ColorDialog();
        colorDlg.AllowFullOpen = true;
        colorDlg.AnyColor = true;

        if (colorDlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            this.SelectedColor = colorDlg.Color;


        }
    }

   void Cancel()
   {
       this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
       this.Close();
   }

   void Save()
   {
       this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
       this.Close();
   } 
}
```

SettingsForm:

The main form for updating settings, this creates a colour picker form and saved the settings and fires an event if the dialog result of the colour form is an 'ok' result.

```
class SettingsForm
{

   public static event ColourSettingChangedDelegate ColourSettingsChangedEvent;
   public delegate void ColourSettingChangedDelegate(Color color);

   void SelectColour()
   {
      using (ColourForm colourForm = new ColourForm())
      {
         if (colourForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
         {
            //Update colour setting and fire event
            OnColourSettingsChanged(colourForm.SelectedColour);
         }
      }
   }

   private void OnColourSettingsChanged(Color color)
   {
      if (ColourSettingsChangedEvent!=null)
        ColourSettingsChangedEvent(color);
   }
}
```

On you Main Form:

The Main form listens for a settings / colour changed event and changes the panel colour to the colour specified in the event when it fires.

```
class MainForm()
{
    //Constructor
    MainForm()
    {
       SettingsForm.ColourSettingsChangedEvent += ColourSettingsChanged;
    }

    void ColourSettingsChanged(Color color)
    {
      upperpanel.BackColor = color;
    }
}
```

it would be better to have some kind of settings manager class than have the event on the settings form itself but you should get the idea

Comment: Yes,Steve is right - `upperpanel` is in the `MainForm`

Comment: @Steve,@WraithNath Thank you for the replies, but nothing happens when i choose the color and I can not figure out where the problem is. the program does not show any errors.

Comment: @Steve @WraithNath , i just edited my `SettingsForm` code. Maybe nothing happens because there is a two lists at `public SettingsForm(List<string> adr, List<string> s)` ?! I really don't know where is the problem with all that well explained example by WraithNath.

Comment: @valeo - your settings screen looks ok, but the colour screen still needs some changes made to it, if you have a look at my example I have added a property to store the selected colour, and methods to save and cancel the changes. I'm guessing your project does not build at the moment but if you make the changes to the colour form it should then work. it might be worth reading an overview of passing data between forms, see the properties approach here https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14122/Passing-Data-Between-Forms